# Bash pipe output to more

Tags: bash, pipe, settings, shell-builtin

I am wondering about some bash environment setting here: is it possible to set stdout of bash as a pipe to /bin/more? You know, like using vi as editor for your commands it should be possible to avoid using Ctrl-PgUp or Ctrl-PgDown for looking on all the output (by default).

To be more specific: I *don't* want to pipe the output of a *single* command to more like:

```
$> ls | more
a b c
...
--more--
```

BUT: 
pipe *any* output of my current session to more, so to get either all output printet as usual just beneath the prompt - or if it's too much, screen-wise.

```
# automatically piped to more:
$> ls 
a b c
...
--more--
```

Is there any bash-built-in to accomplish this?

EDIT: I wasn't specific enough, sorry for that:
I am aware of "script" and command grouping like

```
(cmdA; cmdB) | less
```

What I really would like is to automatically avoid getting a 100 page output at once but instead have a more-like behavior of bash'es stdout. As could be accomplished by adding

```
 2>&1 | more
```

to all commands entered on command promt - just automatically.

Comment: To `vi` and `less` and `su` commands as well? How are those going to get input from you if `more` is taking it?

Comment: Good point...*question closed*

Comment: Running your shell inside Emacs has a lot of nice features. Of course, if you are a `vi`ctim, the cause may already be lost.

Comment: Good idea - obviously I wouldn't do emacs: but for members of the "cult of VI": http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not specific enough as to what you are trying to achieve. I'll take a few guesses:

If you would like to keep track of anything that happens in a session, use `script`. See `man script` for more information.

If you would like to combine the output of multiple commands into one block piped into `less` use braces like so:

```
(date; echo; cat /etc/hosts; echo; cat /etc/resolv.conf; echo; host bla.bla) | less
```

Using more concurrently while typing into the shell won't work as both the shell as well as `less` will want to read the keyboard from `stdin`. That's why we have page up and down and search facilities in terminal programs nowadays.

Comment: Hi Coroos, thanks for your quick reply. I am aware of script and command-grouping. What I meant is like adding a ' 2>&1 | more' to the end of each command I enter.

Comment: Ok, with the comment of Stephane Chazelas I understood your last point - didn't think it through obviously...bash cannot distinguish whether the stdout of a program is applicable for more or whether it is "live" (as vi output)